# Using a list of values to specify the index location at which to insert a new row

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe, insert, row

I have a dataframe (220 rows × 2 columns) and a list of values [41, 84, 129, 174, 219, 45]. I want to insert new rows (containing -999, -999) into my dataframe below the index locations specified within my list. So for example.

```
40   400  -47.595322  
41   410   13.159509  
42     0 -235.865433  
43     8 -102.183365
```

Would become:

```
40   400  -47.595322  
41   410   13.159509  
42   -999  -999  
43     0 -235.865433  
44     8 -102.183365
```

And so on and so on...
Thanks :)

What I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
path =r'MyPath'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.dat")

frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=None, header=None)
    list_.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(list_)
frame.columns = ['age', 'dt']
frame = frame.reset_index(drop=True)
idx = [] + list(frame['age'][frame['age'] == 410].index) + [df.index[-1]+1]
idx = np.array(idx)

df = pd.DataFrame(
np.insert(frame.values, idx + 1, -999, axis=0), columns=frame.columns)


print(df.to_string())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe contains a monotonically increasing index, you can do this quite simply with `np.insert`:

```
idx = np.array([41, 84, 129, 174, 219, 45])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.insert(df.values, idx + 1, -999, axis=0), columns=df.columns
)
```

If not, you'll need to call `index.get_loc` to get the right index in the array:

```
idx = [df.index.get_loc(i) + 1 for i in idx]
```

And call the insert code as before.

---

Demo:

```
df
    A    B           C
0  40  400  -47.595322
1  41  410   13.159509
2  42    0 -235.865433
3  43    8 -102.183365

idx = np.array([1, 3])
pd.DataFrame(
    np.insert(df.values, idx + 1, -999, axis=0), columns=df.columns
)

       A      B           C
0   40.0  400.0  -47.595322
1   41.0  410.0   13.159509
2 -999.0 -999.0 -999.000000
3   42.0    0.0 -235.865433
4   43.0    8.0 -102.183365
5 -999.0 -999.0 -999.000000
```

Beware of invalid index accesses.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this for the most part, your code works well, but for some curious reason, a line is being added at index 48 even though this value isn't on the list. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @user9454050 Can you check again please? That shouldn't happen :)

Comment: I restarted my notebook and ran it again. Still appending to index 48...

Comment: @user9454050 Can you please create a [mcve] in your question? I'll try and see if I can debug it

Comment: @user9454050 Your code is one thing, but I need the data that can reproduce this issue. Is it possible? At least a few rows, whatever is enough to show me that this doesn't work... it works for me.

Comment: @user9454050 Okay, what are the `idx` values for this data?

Comment: The idx values are [41, 84, 129, 174, 219, 45]. But the way the code is written, these values would change if the structure of the input files change.

Comment: @user9454050 Hmm, I don't think so, because those indices don't exist in the data provided.

Comment: Looking at it now I can see why im having a problem. the idx list contains 45 which is invalid. If i figure out how that is getting into my idx list then the problem should resolve.

Comment: @user9454050 Does that happen before you do `idx = [df.index.get_loc(i) + 1 for i in idx]` or after?

Comment: fixed. Removing `+ [df.index[-1]+1]` has resolved the issue. Thanks for your help.